# Can a List be a @WebMethod parameter in java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I am implementing a SOAP service in Java. My parameters from the XML request are like

```
<change>
  <id>1</id>
</change>
<change>
  <id>2</id>
</change>
```

There is a corresponding Java class:

```
public class ChangeXML {
  @XmlElement(name = "id")
  private long itemId;

  .......
}
```

I know that this structure is not optimal, but it's also not exactly what I have - this is a simplification.

Can I map this structure as a `@WebParamter` in my `@WebMethod`?

```
(@WebParam(name = "change") final List<ChangeXML> change)
```

Or do I have to introduce another element `<changes>` and class `ChangesXML` to hold the list of changes?

Comment: No. You can use list of `ChangesXML` directly as input parameters. You don't need to create another class for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to wrap that List?

I would like it to look like

```
<changes>
   <change>
      <id>1</id>
   </change>
   <change>
      <id>2</id>
   </change>
</changes>
```